# How to recognize recycler if both use the same adapter?

Tags: android

I got recyclerOne and recyclerTwo. Both of them use the same adapter and same item layout. I need to set recyclerOne item text color to black and recyclerTwo item text color to blue. How to recognize inside adapter view holder which recycler items it handles to set the correct color in `onBind()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take a parameter in the `adapter` constructor like this:

```
class MyAdapter(private var mList: ArrayList<YourList>, private val check: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

Then in the `onBindView`, you can check which `RecyclerView` set the `adapter` like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (check == 1) // set item color to black
    else if (check == 2) // set item color to blue
}
```

And lastly, while setting the `adapter`, you can pass the check parameter like this:

**For recyclerOne:**

```
val adapter = MyAdapter(myList, 1)
binding.recyclerOne.adapter = adapter
```

**For recyclerTwo:**

```
val adapter = MyAdapter(myList, 2)
binding.recyclerTwo.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: ye I did actually the same way but instead of number I just passed boolean isFirst. And passed it with the init process

Comment: That's great! :)